# pass key event to listview content

Tags: android, listview, focus

I have a listview

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollHeader="@color/blue"
        android:overScrollMode="always" />
```

the elements contain some views and a horizontalscrollview

```
...
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
...

    </HorizontalScrollView>
...
```

What I can't figure it out is how to make the horizontallscrollview move for the focused element in listview when pressing the left or right key. (How to send the key event to the horizontalscrollview)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `Activity` and `View` class implement the `KeyEvent.Callback` interface which methods you can use to handle keyboard actions. When you'll catch particular key event use `HorizontalScrollView#executeKeyEvent`. You can call this function yourself to have the scroll view perform scrolling from a key event, just as if the event had been dispatched to it by the view hierarchy.

Comment: So you are saying to capture manually the key event and send it to the HorizontalScrollView? I was hoping for something like passing automatically the key event from that focus to the element inside

Comment: Well, your `HorizontalScrollView` will get key event if it is focused. However when the View which is currently focused is not `HorizontalScrollView` directly but its parent View then Android will pass key event only to parent View. You then need to pass key event to child View manually.